# It´s a way to set multiple color paths in Google Static Map?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Right now i have a dynamically generated google static map image with a path drawed in it. That path it´s composed by 'x' number of separated paths, and i want to set a different color for each one, but i can´t find a way to do that, (if it´s possible). I´m working in PHP.

Now i have something like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' . $latitude . ',' . $longitude . '&zoom=15&format=jpg&size=640x640&scale=4&maptype=hybrid&markers=icon:http://myweburl/myownmarkerimage.png%7Clabel:C%7C' . $markerlat . ',' . $markerlong . '&path=color:0x0517bcDD| . $pathpoints
```

That code is working perfectly, but the path has one color. I want to change that color for each 'pathpoint'. I tried to declare multiple path tag on the URL, and multiple color selectors, but nothing worked.

Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: What is `$pathpoints`?  A line can only have one color, so for different colored segments, you need to break the original line into one piece for each contiguous colored segment.

Comment: The var $pathpoints contains an string with all latitude and longitude points that i want to print.

So its not possible to print different path segment in the same static map, right?

Comment: It should be possible to draw multiple polylines of different colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add multiple paths to a static map.  Each path has a single color:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0x0000FF80|weight:5|37.401528,-122.11372|37.3955278,-122.1018791&path=color:0xFF000080|weight:5|37.3955278,-122.101879|37.38789,-122.0883&path=color:0x00FF0080|weight:5|37.38789,-122.08866|37.380388,-122.072697&size=500x300
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/StaticMapWithMultiplePolylines.html)

[image]

Note however, there is a maximum length allowed for the URL.

You can also use [encoded polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) to specify the path:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0x0000FF80|weight:5|enc:_|gcFthihV|a@_iA&path=color:0xFF000080|weight:5|enc:ayfcFp|fhV`m@qpA&path=color:0x00FF0080|weight:5|enc:mzccFnkahVqo@n~A&size=500x300
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/StaticMapWithMultipleEncodedPolylines.html)

[image]